# How to clear erroneous unread sms indicator

Tags: sms, notifications, app-icons

I am using the stock SMS app on Android 4.1.2.  I received an SMS message and read it but when I return to my home screen, the `(1)` in the top right corner of the app is still there.  Inside the messaging app, it lists no messages as unread on any of my threads.  I have tried killing the SMS app, restarting the phone, and even using a third party app that marks all your SMS as read, but the notification indicator on the app icon persists.  How do I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Application manager.  Find an application called "Badge Provider" and clear it's data.  Then restart the phone.  The `(1)` goes away.